# How to verify `extern "C"` definition signature matches implementation

Tags: rust

Given the following files:

`main.rs`:

```rust
mod ffi;
mod impl_do_print;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        ffi::do_print(42.0);
    }
}
```

`ffi.rs`:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn do_print(x: f32);
}
```

`impl_do_print.rs`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn do_print(x: i32) {
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

Obviously, the `f32` of the definition and the `i32` of the implementation don't match.

When I execute this, it prints:

```
1047505936
```

I understand that `no_mangle` is automatically considered `unsafe`, but is there any way I could ask the compiler to catch the mismatch, or would I have to write my own linter for this?

**Usecase:**
This question came up with generated FFIs. I am able to modify the implementation in any way possible, but I cannot edit the function definition, as it is generated via `bindgen`.

Comment: Why are the extern interface definition and the extern function implementation in the same crate? The `extern "C" { ... }` is for defining the interfaces for calling functions provided by external libraries. The `extern "C" fn ...` is for defining functions that can be called by users of your library.

Comment: @PitaJ this is a little modified because my original question was too convoluted. The usecase is that an external crate requires the user to define a specific function, and then the external crate will *call* the function. To make sure it matches, the external crate publishes the definition in a header file. To be more specific, I'm trying to write a Rust interface for `OpenThread`, which [requires just that](https://openthread.io/guides/porting/implement-platform-abstraction-layer-apis).

Comment: Is `ffi.rs` already generated at the time of compiling `impl_do_print.rs`, i.e. can we use `ffi:*` in `impl_do_print.rs`?

Comment: @NiklasMohrin Yes. I was wondering about something like that, as well. Why are you asking? Are you going towards proc macros? Just adding `ffi:*` gives you a duplicate definition error, though, I tried that already. But I would have been surprised if that worked, tbh.

Comment: Okay so what you really want is a way to check that the `extern "C"` functions you export match the header file.

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, exactly. I tried to write the full story in a previous question, but it got so confusing that nobody knew what I was talking about :)

Comment: What I would do is write a script or something to convert `extern "C" { pub fn foo() }` to `pub extern "C" fn foo() { crate::impl_ffi::foo() }`

Comment: @PitaJ That's not a bad idea. I shall play around with it.

Comment: It's hard to verify whether signatures match their actual implementations, because after compiling, all the type information is lost and you're left with just the symbol name of the function. Generating the definitions from a common source is a common way of keeping them in sync.

Comment: I summed up all the ideas I got so far in an answer. Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, two potentially viable solutions were proposed:

- Use the `ffi.rs` to auto-generate an implementation for the method that simply forwards the call to my own implementation. That way, the compiler would catch mismatching arguments.
- Use the `ffi.rs` to generate a `type` definition for the function. That way, you could write a compiler check to verify that the implementation matches the definition, like this: `const _: fn_type = fn_impl`.

Either way, it seems to require proc macros or an external generator.

---

After a little more experimenting, I managed to achieve a compile time check by utilizing a macro:

`impl_do_print.rs`:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn do_print(x: i32) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

macro_rules! check_implementation_type {
    ($t:ty, $name:ident) => {
        const _: $t = $name;
        const _: $t = crate::ffi::$name;
    };
}

check_implementation_type!(unsafe extern "C" fn(i32), do_print);
```

This still requires me to write a `check_implementation_type` entry for every function I implement, but it gives me a reliable compile time error if either the `ffi.rs` or the implementation don't match:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/impl_do_print.rs:9:23
   |
9  |         const _: $t = crate::ffi::$name;
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found `f32`
...
13 | check_implementation_type!(unsafe extern "C" fn(i32), do_print);
   | --------------------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `unsafe extern "C" fn(i32)`
                 found fn item `unsafe extern "C" fn(f32) {ffi::do_print}`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `check_implementation_type` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```